# NET 4.6.1, NET 4.5.2 and CRM 2016

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2012-r2, dynamics-crm-2016, .net-4.5.2, .net-4.6.1

I have Net 4.5.2, in Windows 2012 R2, and CRM 2016 installed.

I use VS 2013.

I want créate WCF Services .NET 4.6.1, and hosting in IIS 8.5 in the  Windows 2012 R2 + CRM 2016 server.

CRM 2016 manages Net 4.5.2.

Any problems if I install  Targeting Pack .NET Framework 4.6.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Dynamics CRM 2016 is compatible with IIS 8.5 and Framework 4.6.1.

You may already be aware of this but the targeting pack is only going to give you support within VS.  You'll need the 4.6.1 framework upgrade installed on the server not the targeting pack.  As 4.6.1 is an in place upgrade of framework 4.x all applications on the server will now be using it so test accordingly.

Any particular reason you want to target 4.6.1 in your WCF services?

Comment: Forums Microsoft Dynamic CRM: `NET 4.6.1, .NET 4.5.2 AND CRM 2016` _https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/213613/565160#565160_

**Installing 4.6.1 won't create any problem, but you can only write extension for Dynamics CRM 2016 using 4.5.2 which is supported at this point.**

Comment: installed on the server **NET Framework 4.6.1 Runtime** not the _NET Framework 4.6.1 targeting pack_ ?

Comment: target 4.6.1 in your WCF services ? IMHO, better performance, and improvements with lastest version